# Render PDF in SSRS 2008 with digital signature block

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, digital-signature

We are using SSRS 2008 to render pdf reports for our users. They would like the capability to digitally sign these reports. Is there anyway to add a digital signature block to a pdf file using SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

If by Digital Signature, you are referring to assigning a security certificate to the PDF file, then no, the Render method of the ReportViewer control will definitely not be able to accomplish this.

One idea would be to generate the PDF file as you are currently doing, then open the PDF file programatically and sign it.  Basically, a two step process.

Unfortunately, you will need to find some libraries that will support this operation, or write your own.

Comment: I don't know if it's what Joe meant, but we are trying to generate an EMPTY block where the digital signature will end up once signed (using Adobe Echosign btw).